# Read frame size of view from storyboard

Tags: ios, ios5, storyboard

I'm developing app that uses storyboards, that needs to reposition elements after rotation in a way that isn't possible with spring and struts.

Setting it to where I want it to be when rotated is easy enough, I just set view's frame in 
willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration: method.

However, if I want to go back to portrait mode, I need to put all elements where they where when they came out out of storyboard.

So, is there a way to programatically read what would those values be, or do I need to hardcode them?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the values of the controls in some variable for both portrait of landscape, and depending on your orientation in the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` method, position them accordingly.

This post here would be helpful for you: [View Resize and rotate](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPad_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling_%28Xcode_4%29)

AFAIK, the code does not store the value of the control's location once you change orientation.